# Share a Rclone mounted drive with samba

Tags: linux, smb, rclone

i mounted a google drive storage on my ubuntu machine using rclone with the following syntax:

rclone -vv mount --vfs-cache-mode full --daemon google-test: /test --allow-other

the first problem occurs when i try to run this command with non root user , it takes about one minute and returns a "mount is not ready error" , i solved this issue with root user but i prefer to use non root user

the second part is after mounting the google drive i am trying to share this storage for all devices on my LAN , i used smb and configure the share point as following:

```
[test3]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu3
    path = /test3
    read only = no
    browsable = yes
    writeable = Yes
```

and i set my user password over samba

after connect i notice that i have only read permission over network, but locally i have full privileges and i have no idea what is the problem

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Might not directly be the answer you are looking for but it has to do with 'user' and file/directory permissions.

Before giving the answer, it is *bad* practice to re-share a non-local filesystem through another service.

In the past with NFS we ran into the same problem and opening up full read/write/execute permissions on the network storage (NFS / or google drive in your case ) was one (awful) solution.

In general, your network mount allows a specific user to access all files. As you stated, locally you have full access. The user used by Samba might not be the same user.